# JAXB messing up encoding in Mule flow

Tags: jaxb, mule, anypoint-studio

I'm running a flow in Mule CE and have huge problems with encodings. No matter what I do my files end up with messed up non-english charcters.

Before the jaxb-object-to-xml transformer my payload looks nice in the console and in the debugger, but after that it's all messed up.

```
    ......   
    <http:request>
    <object-to-byte-array-transformer encoding="UTF-8" doc:name="Object to Byte Array"/>
    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="String" encoding="UTF-8"/> 
    <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.List"  doc:name="JSON2ObjectList" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter"/>
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
       <when expression="....">
        <custom-transformer returnClass="se.system.Order.SalesHeader"  class="se.system.Transformer.Map2Order" doc:name="Map2Order" mimeType="application/xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>
        <mulexml:jaxb-object-to-xml-transformer name="orderMarshaller" jaxbContext-ref="JAXB_Context" doc:name="orderMarshaller"  mimeType="text/xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="XML2String" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <set-variable variableName="fileName" value="order-#[function:dateStamp].xml" doc:name="fileName" encoding="UTF-8"/>       
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="${file.ToOrder}" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" outputPattern="#[fileName]" mimeType="text/xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>
```

After the jaxb transformer non-english characters looks like:

```
Deliveryinfo2="Ã¥ Ã¤ Ã¶ Ã… Ã„ Ã– &amp; % Ã¨ Ã‰"/
```

And the 010 editor claims its ANSI DOS (with messed up characters, don't know if that one is to be trusted though)
Have I missed something in the jaxb transformer? or somewhere else?
Is it possible to replace it with a Java component, initiate my very own JAXB context, get a marshaller and handle it myself?
No clues anymore...

Regards

EDIT: this one can handle non-english characters

```
<mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML" encoding="UTF-8" />
```

but not GregorianCalendar types or my main Objects List of other objects so it's  not an alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug caused by the JAXB transformer not respecting the given encoding, see [source](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-4.x/modules/xml/src/main/java/org/mule/runtime/module/xml/transformer/jaxb/JAXBMarshallerTransformer.java) (line 64).

What however is kinda weird is that according to the [JAXB documentation](https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.4/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html) the default encoding should be UTF-8.

> **Encoding**
>
> By default, the Marshaller will use UTF-8 encoding when generating XML data to a java.io.OutputStream, or a java.io.Writer. Use the setProperty API to change the output encoding used during these marshal operations. Client applications are expected to supply a valid character encoding name as defined in the W3C XML 1.0 Recommendation and supported by your Java Platform.

This should probably be something like this

```
final Marshaller m = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, encoding);
```